# Is there a way to set the extra value in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so I have this relationship in Rails:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :positions

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :users, :through => :positions
```

Here is the schema for positions:

```
create_table "positions", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
  t.boolean  "regular_user", :default => true
end
```

The `regular_user` is signaling the admins and the employees so my question is how do set the `regular_user` to `0` or `false` from this data:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
@user.companies << @company
```

Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking:

```
Position.create(user_id: params[:user_id], company_id: params[:company_id], regular_user: 0)
```

But is there a standard for setting associations?

Comment: You say "set to `0` or `false`", but note that in Ruby `0` is not `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  has_many :companies, :through => :positions
  has_many :companies_as_non_regular_user, :through => :positions, 
           :conditions => {:"positions.regular_user" => false}
  ...
end

@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
@user.companies_as_non_regular_user << @company
```